# How to find mutual number from the text file using MapReduce?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I am New to MapReduce and I am working on a project to increase my knowledge.
Now I have to write a MapReduce Program in Hadoop for mutual friend finding from a chunk of data.

Input file is in the format

```
<User><TAB><Friends>
```

It is a text file with data like

```
0   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94
1   0,5,20,135,2409,8715,8932,10623,12347,12846,13840,13845,14005,20075,21556,22939,23520,28193,29724,29791,29826,30691,31232,31435,32317,32489,34394,35589,35605,35606,35613,35633,35648,35678,38737,43447,44846,44887,49226,49985,623,629,4999,6156,13912,14248,15190,17636,19217,20074,27536,29481,29726,29767,30257,33060,34250,34280,34392,34406,34418,34420,34439,34450,34651,45054,49592
2   0,117,135,1220,2755,12453,24539,24714,41456,45046,49927,6893,13795,16659,32828,41878
3   0,12,41,55,1532,12636,13185,27552,38737
4   0,8,14,15,18,27,72,80,15326,19068,19079,24596,42697,46126,74,77,33269,38792,38822
5   0,1,20,2022,22939,23527,30257,32503,35633,41457,43262,44846,49574,31140,32828
```

So, 1,2,3,4,5, and so on means the tag while the numbers that are written in front of them are their friends. What I have to do is:

1. provide mutual friends recommendations from this chunk of data
2. Only one MapReduce job can solve this problem.
3. Output should be the format `<User><TAB><Recommendations>`

I do not know where to start.

Comment: please ask a specific question and list what you have tried so far

Comment: there are subparts in my question.

Comment: and I am not able to do it. I need Help from scratch.

Comment: well, that's unfortunate, but we can't do your tasks for you, that's not what stackoverflow is for. If you are stuck on a specific problem, feel free to open another question.

Comment: I do not know where to start sir. I am just 16.

Comment: "How to start" questions really are too broad here. If you can cut your question down to something smaller, that is ideal. Some hints on how to ask questions [are here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this approach:

a. try creating k, list pair where k is the number shown as friends and v is the users.
for e.g.: (1, <0,5>), (20, <1, 5>), (5, <0,1>)
  This would be the output of the mappers.

b.  In reducer, collect all keys. 
    and check size of values, 
          if size(value) >= 2 ==> this key is a mutual friend.

c. recommend this mutual friend to other friends i.e other than the values in this key.

d. Format the output in the manner you need.

This could be only one of the possible solutions... 
Do share if you think any other solutions are more feasible.